# Question explanation - squares in cubes

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry

I am faced with the following question and neither do I know what the author wants from me, nor do I know how to approach the problem.

> Let $b(R)$ and $s(R)$ be the number of integer unit cubes in $\mathbb{R}^m$ that intersect the ball and sphere of radius R, centered at the origin. a) Let $m = 2$ and calculate the limits $\lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{s(R)}{b(R)}$ and $\lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{s(R)^2}{b(R)}$.

How could I even go about this question? I'm afraid I can't even tell you any approach I've made apart from just plugging in R = 1, R = 2, R=3,  etc. Help greatly appreciated! I looked at some other answers on stackexchange already and they didn't help me out, so I'm hoping someone can dumb it down for me a bit.

Comment: By "integer unit cubes" I assume the author means cubes (filled-in squares in $\Bbb R^2$) with side length $1$ who vertices all have integer coordinates.  In other words, the $m$-dimensional equivalent of a lattice.

Comment: In 2 dimensions the ball is a disk, a filled in circle.  A sphere is the perimeter of the disk, the (unfilled) circle.  For large $R$ the details of the squares will not matter.  For the disk you can just use the area and justify that the error is rather small because it is near the circle.  For the circle you have to think about it-how many squares hit a large circle?

Comment: @RossMillikan okay, so I thought about it and this is what I got - if you only consider discrete R as I originally did (R = 1, 2, etc.) then it appears to me that as you increase the radius the number of squares touching the perimeter increases by the next largest odd number in each quadrant. so for instance, for R = 1, fix any quadrant and in it the number of squares intersecting the sphere is 1. For R = 2, it is 3, and so on. So I assume the number of squares hitting the sphere goes to infinity right?

Comment: For squares touching the sphere you don't count the ones that are completely within the circle, only those that touch the circumference.  The number does go to infinity, but you are asked for the limits of two ratios.  In both ratios the numerator and denominator go to infinity with large $R$ so you need to see how fast they go.

Comment: I'd like to see a "proof without words" type solution for the second limit.